# How to access and use a dylib in an Obj-C application?

Tags: c, macos, dylib

I've made a dylib that contains the following code:

```
    Test.h:

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface Test : NSObject {
     int number;
}
-(void)beep;
-(void)giveInt:(int)num;
-(int)takeInt;

@end


Test.m:

#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

-(void)beep {
     NSBeep();
}
-(void)giveInt:(int)num {
     number = num;
}
-(int)takeInt {
     return number;
}

@end
```

I've compiled the dylib and put it in another project but I can't seem to figure out how to make a Test object from the dylib and call some of the methods.
Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Just fyi: Dynamic libraries are loaded at runtime. If you don't need to load code dynamically, link statically.

Anyway:

```
#import "test.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    void *handle = dlopen("test.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    id t = [[NSClassFromString(@"Test") alloc] init];

    [t beep];
    [t release];

    dlclose(handle);
    [pool drain];
}
```

You'll want to include some error checking, but that's the basic idea. If you want to use NSBundle (which may be more "proper" depending on the circumstances, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html)

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to work. I would post my code but I can't figure out how to do the code tags.

Comment: I set it up so I create a Test object globally and the beep never happens even though I call it.

Comment: Replace the NSBeep call with something more reliable (e.g. printf)

Comment: Don't forget about using the debugger.  Step through the code and make sure handle is non-nil. If it's nil, your dylib is not being found or not loaded for whatever reason.  You can set a breakpoint in the dylib too.